# External use of Django DB module failed because of settings module loading

Tags: python, django

I am facing a problem with using Django DB module in an external gateway script. 
I have the following python file under 
**myproject/myapplication/lib.py**

```
#<path>/myproject/myapplication/lib.py
from django.db import connection
from django.db import settings

#SOME METHODS ARE HERE
```

which is using django db module.

I need to import **lib** in another python script under the same directory **myproject/myapplication/gateway.py**

```
#<path>/myproject/myapplication/gateway.py
import sys, os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "myproject.settings"
sys.path.append('../')
import lib

#SOME LOGIC HERE
```

but it is failing with the following error :

```
Fisbrok:myproject firas$ python myapplication/gateway.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myapplication/gateway.py", line 7, in ?
    import lib
  File ".... lib.py", line 1, in ?
    from django.db import connection
  File "/opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 14, in ?
    if not settings.DATABASES:
  File "/opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
    self._setup()
  File "/opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 75, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'myproject.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named myproject.settings
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

your project directory, `myproject` has to be in python path to set the settings module as `myproject.settings`

you can set the project directory on python in the gateway.py file by

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'absolute/path/to/project')
```

before the line

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "myproject.settings"
```